# What is Internet Relay Chat?

Tags: irc

What exactly is "IRC"?

I've read about it on Wikipedia, but I've never seen people using it (or if I have, I didn't recognize it). The only kind of "chat" I know about are those of AIM, Yahoo! Messenger, etc...

i.e. What is IRC typically used for, and what are its advantages compared to other (more "normal") chat services?

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but i'm rather shocked people don't know what irc is ;p

Comment: @journeyman: lol... hopefully it's not as bad as [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for)? :P

Comment: prolly worse. unlike floppy drives, IRC is still commonly used.

Comment: @journeyman: ouch...

Comment: Seriously, when I started chatting on IRC back in 1995, nobody knew about it. It kinda never got enough casualty, so it never seemed to penetrate into global attention, things like social websites now subsided it. I use it every day, though, It's still my favorite chat system, second is Skype. Interestingly, some web services use IRC as backend for chats, UStream for instance. I'll stay with IRC as long as it will prevail...

Comment: It was very popular between 1996 and until around 2002 I think. A lot of people I know who did not work in IT used it.

Comment: I witnessed the [mIRC](http://www.mirc.com/) craziness at late 90s.

Comment: @Mehper: I like how mIRC is on version 7, and Google Chrome is on version 13...

Comment: IRC is [like two ships meeting in the ocean](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2rGTXHvPCQ)

Comment: @Phoshi: [...](http://assets.sbnation.com/assets/562900/facepalm.jpg)

Comment: @Mehrdad; Okay, it's nothing like two ships meeting in the ocean

Comment: @Phoshi: I was more referring to the fact that someone already posted this. :P

Comment: @mehrdad have you looked at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat)

Comment: I think it's pretty normal that IRC is not known to people under 20. Old(!) people has usually no idea about which technologies become obsolete.

Comment: @TFM; I wouldn't say IRC was obsolete, it still powers an awful lot of web-based chats, as well as still being the best group chat room solution. It can't become obsolete until there's something better than it, after all.

Comment: If you don't know IRC, you will scare when somebody show you a terminal with screen and irssi in a remote server :P

Comment: @Juan : or they will suspect you of being a haxxor. ;p

Comment: It's really shocking how microsoft brainwashed every computer user with windows. There are so many tools out there brought by the OSS community microsoft has blown away because they wanted to impose their product, and only their product. I'm just so disappointed to see that computers are not what they used to be: one piece of hardware with which you can do hundreds of things, unless of course you take some time to learn about it. Today it's just MSN, facebook, twitter, gmail, your photo folder, and that's it, you used your computer. So disappointing.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's an old fashioned chat system, that's very useful for group chat - and many Linux distros use it for informal support. Its strength and weakness is its simplicity - It pretty much won't do anything other than text by default, though there's ways to send files through it as well.

The advantages would be that it works on almost any net-connected system (even when there's no client - there's decent web based front ends), the architecture is fairly simple, it's trivial to run your own server and it's plain text. Authentication is optional, and mostly needed to 'reserve' your nickname or do admin related tasks. It's perfect if you want a service that's anonymous and may have new users pop in at various times.

The disadvantages are by default it's plain text and unless it's a SSL enabled server all your passwords and everything you say can be sniffed by anyone between you and the server.

Comment: And the different networks can vary tremendously from eachother.

Comment: It's also a robust system. The biggest networks manage tens of thousands of channels with up to 1k users on each channel. Still, the lag is expressed in decimals and very rarely exceeds the 1s mark. (translated from german wikipedia: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat)

Comment: The most popular Windows client by far is [mIRC](http://www.mirc.com/).  IRC has faded out of popularity over the years, but it still has its uses: several programming libraries I use provide their support in mIRC.  Also, the best place to find scrims in CounterStrike is still #findscrim

Comment: ***Real men use `telnet` and enter raw IRC commands.*** Or at least they can - I prefer xchat myself.

Comment: I've actually done it. its needing to ping pong that gets on my nerves.

Comment: A comment about SSL usage and IRC: One feature of IRC servers is that they can link with other IRC servers, many "big" IRC networks are exactly that - many servers linked together.  With regard to SSL, while traffic may be protected to the server you connect to in the network, there is no automatic guarantee that connections between servers are SSL.

Answer (score 20):

It's how hackers talk when they don't want to be overheard. It's a pretty primitive chat program. Think of it like shipping channels in the ocean: You can't see them until a boat cuts through the water leaving a wake. If two boats meet in the middle of the ocean to swap illegal drugs, you have to catch them in realtime, otherwise there's no evidence of a meeting left behind.

Comment: +1 for the [reference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2rGTXHvPCQ) ;p

Comment: lol weird analogy but that works I guess, thanks. :) +1

Comment: If anyone wants to downvote this please watch this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2rGTXHvPCQ

Comment: @jcrawfordor: whats so "primitive" at the irc-protocol?

Comment: its plain text - no fancy XML stylings, no binary information. Any simpler, and you'd be sending ascii over telnet.

Comment: +1 because it automatically came to my mind. You were first though :)

Comment: Actually, there are hardcore guys who use telnet/netcat as IRC client :-)

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote. I know the joke, but we're here to provide answers, not laughs.

Comment: @user4197: why can't something be both?

Comment: @vtest I actually had to do that for a while on a system that I couldn't install a working IRC client on, in the days before CGI:IRC and Mibbit. It's actually not that hard, except for the PING and PONG messages that are exchanged between client and server to see if the clients are still there. (The regular TCP mechinisms for detecting a failed connection don't work reliably for IRC servers, for various reasons, probably because the servers are so hardened against ICMP and spoofed RST packets that they can't detect legitimatly dropped connections easily...)

Comment: -1: This is an overly broad statement that applies to pretty much all chat mechanisms, which as a general rule, are not logged.  @Stephanie the normal TCP mechanisms work just fine, but can take up to an hour to notice a failed connection if left idle, hence the forced traffic in the ping/pong messages.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist posting this. That video cracks me up every time. Well, I need to get back to making a GUI in visual basic to track the killer's IP.

Comment: @user4197: it is NOT both.  IRC is in NO way protection from being overheard -- just the opposite.

Comment: @Lee: huh? Did you mean to answer someone else?

Comment: user4197: yes, sorry.  I meant to reply @JoachimSauer.

Comment: 1uck!1y 1 sp33k l33t

Answer (score 9):

IRC (Internet Relay Chat) is a real-time multi-user messaging system. Users connect to an IRC server and join one or multiple channels or enter into one-on-one chats with individual users. Users type in messages (up to a few hundred characters long, I'm not sure what the actual limits are) and send them to the channel they are in. Other people in that channel then receive the messages that everyone else has sent. The server is a central point of contact for the channel and serves as a relay for the messages from each user, thus the name. Additionally, servers can be chained together, relaying their traffic back and forth. Typically, an IRC client will render the conversations in a channel as an upward scrolling list of messages in chronological order, with each message on one or several lines (depending on length) and prefixed with some username identifier and perhaps other information (such as a time stamp) depending on the individual configuration of the client.

There are many other real-time communications systems, but IRC has a few key advantages that keep it relevant even today. IRC is decentralized. There is no single company controlling IRC (in contrast to gchat or facebook chat or AIM, etc.) Anyone can set up their own server and use it however they like.

IRC's channel paradigm is very flexible and allows for real-time discussion with up to hundreds of people at once. Most other chat systems don't have similar capabilities. And though an IRC channel with hundreds of active participants can be difficult or impossible to follow, the general case tends to be that only a fraction of the people in a channel are actively chatting at any given time, with the rest either idle and not participating or merely reading.

IRC has the concept of access levels and complex channel modes. For example, users may be banned from a channel based on their IP address, or a channel may be secret (not showing up in the list of channels on the server) or private and require an invitation or a secret code to enter. A user in a channel may be an operator or administrator (capable of banning people, changing channel modes, etc.) Non-operator users in a "moderated" channel are not able to speak unless they've been given voice by an operator. These options render difficult chat situations (e.g. hundreds of people including folks who wish to be disruptive) manageable.

A typical IRC channel tends to be attached to an event or a community in some way. For example, UStream (real-time video streaming) uses IRC for real-time communication between the streamer and the viewers. The advantages listed above in terms of the ability of an IRC server to be controlled by a specific group and access and control of an IRC channel to be controlled by specific users can help the channel owners maintain as high a level of signal to noise as they desire (by kicking/banning unwanted users, using an invitation only system, moderating a channel, etc.)

IRC is often used by friends or communities as a virtual place to hang out. There's not necessarily any grand purpose to a channel other than for people of similar interests or a group of friends to talk to each other.

IRC can also be used for other purposes, especially if specialized client add-ons or fully autonomous bot-clients are used, such as file-sharing, botnet control, or gaming where messages contain commands instead of just chatter.

Answer (score 3):

It's a oldschool way to communicate.

In the begining of the "internet era" it was popular because (besides comunicating with people you know) you were able to get to know new people just by accident, knowing them only from subject of the channel they're connected and from their nickname.

First you have to install IRC client, then connect to server and then to the room (or channel). You were able to talk in 'common' (open) channel where everyone talked or in private with somebody.

OP (from Operator) of this room was able to "kick" aggresive users, trolls etc, OP were able to ban users from room for amount of time (they couldn't reconnect to the room) if they were very annoing or (for example) for spaming links.

---

It was so popular too becouse anyone with some skills could "listen" to lots of conversations :)

Answer (score 1):

I myself have been one of those people who never understood the purpose of IRC, until recently where I found one reason I could actually use it for.

Whenever you have one of those questions which doesn't quite deserve it's own thread, since you know the answer will be short, IRC is a great way to just briefly state your question and usually get a reply faster than you could by creating a forum-thread.

Also, many forums have lots of rules and they tend to be more formal. So thread-creators often pick their words carefully, put lots of work into their question since it will most likely stay there linked to their identity for a long long time for anyone to see.

From my experience, IRC is usually more casual and less strict, where asking a quick question without providing too many details is not something that will immediately cause negative reactions from people.

After learning about IRC, I was surprised how many websites/projects/communities actually have one which are active. Whenever your in doubt, just Google the name +IRC. I got an iphone a few days ago, had a question in regards to jailbreaking, so I just googled "jailbreak irc", and instantly got in touch with people who had massive experience and could help me out :)

Answer (score 1):

IRC can also be used to open a channel to a single recipient, thus ensuring a "private chat."  It's been so long since I used the program though that I forget the command.  File transfers through IRC are also very fast.