# Notepad++ Explorer Plugin not showing all Partitions

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, notepad++, plugins

My PC has 3 partitions **C, U and A**. I installed Explorer Plugin in Notepad++, it shows the two partitions properly.
But for some reason the third partition is not there. I have a lot of project files in that partition.

How can I get that partition listed in Explorer Pane ?

[image]

[image]

**Other Info:**
All partitions are NTFS
Notepad++ Install Directory: **C** (OS root is also C)
Notepad++ **v6.1.6**
Explorer Plugin **v5.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it won't show B: either, if you had it.

Try something like `subst i: a:\`, then see if the plugin displays I: or not.

---

Edit: Ok, so I see my guess was indeed correct, and the solution above works. As for why this is, well I'm no expert but we all know (or should know) [how Windows treats A: and B: differently](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for), so there's still a lot of software out there that expects to see long-term storage on the C: (and greater, so should those be called C++?) drives. No doubt this 'bug' affects the Explorer plugin for Notepad++ as well, which is why it doesn't display the A: and B: drives. SUBSTing either of these with another drive letter creates an alias that obviously the plugin has no problems displaying.

As for the problem of SUBSTed drives not persisting across reboots, there's a slight trick to accomplishing this. You can use the following command:

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices" /v I: /t REG_SZ /d "\??\A:\" /f`

to make the mapping persistent across reboots. Further details available in [Wikipedia's article on SUBST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST#Persisting_across_reboots), as well as [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/29072/how-to-make-subst-mapping-persistent-across-reboots). You can also use the [psubst batch file](http://code.google.com/p/psubst/) which makes it easy to create normal or persistent SUBSTed drives.

Comment: Awesome, that works. Only problem is that now I have to do it at every boot.

Comment: It would be better if you can shed more light on the issue, for learning purpose ("teach me how to fish" style ;-)). Like- What was the problem ? and How `subst` solves it ?

Comment: @Lamb: Sure, now that I know it works, I've edited my answer to add more details.

Comment: thanks a lot, you said "I'm no expert" but now I think you lied :)

Comment: One more thing What If I simply change the Drive letter from Disk Management to I:. Will it affect anything else in my system ?
Will it solve the persistent problem without this Registry tweaking ?

Comment: @Lamb: As long as it's just a data drive or has only portable apps, I don't think changing the drive letter should cause any problems at all. Of course if you have programs installed on it with paths stored in the registry and elsewhere, they may or may not break when the drive letter's changed.