# Can you assign multiple drive letters to a drive, one for each partition?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ms-dos

By this I mean if I have two partitions on a drive, can I mount one as a separate drive letter and use the other as a boot for an os? I am not planning to dual-boot, I need a separate drive for my second OS and don't want to waste a 500gb hard drive on a small partition to be used only with a change of the boot order. If there is another way to do this and still be able to use the extra space on my first OS, I'm all ears.

Comment: Windows treats each partition as a logical drive.  If Windows recognizes/supports the filesystem of that partition, then you must assign a drive letter to that logical drive for access.

Answer (score 2):

"Drive letters" *are* always assigned to partitions. (They're only called drive letters because they existed for years [before](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for) PCs had HDDs which could be partitioned, and the name stuck.)

So if you have a disk with two NTFS partitions, they will both have individual drive letters (or folder mountpoints).

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit new to this side of windows, I deal more with advanced programming languages.