# My hard drive (A:) shows no letter in processes but in disk management it appears correctly

Tags: hardware-detection

My hard drive (A:) shows no letter in processes but in disk management it appears correctly.

Is this an issue? And if it is how can I fix it?

I am experiencing issues with my hardware and trying to locate where is the problem. This internal disk keeps disconnecting while I am playing a game installed in this disk.

Here is a screenshot where hard disk has no letter:

> [image: Hard Disk 0 has no letter]
> [disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWwDB.png)

Comment: Which disk keeps disconnecting exactly?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: [What are the Windows `A:` and `B:` drives used for?](https://superuser.com/q/231273/432690)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for a disk to have multiple [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning). Some of these are mounted, i.e. currently available for use, and in Windows OS, they may be assigned drive letters. However, there may be many other currently unmounted partitions., as shown below in *diskmgmt.msc*.

[image: Disk partitions]

Notice that partitions 1 though 7 are used for Windows Recovery, EFI (boot), or other purposes; only the NTFS partition is given a letter,C:.

Whatever the cause for your problem, "disk keeps disconnecting", it has nothing to do with the disk layout.

BTW, the letters A: and B: were reserved for archaic *floppy* drives. These were successors to such devices as mercury [delay-line memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_line_memory); consult an archaeologist for information.

If the game is copy-protected, it might "disconnect" if the protection scheme is violated.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This particular disk does not have any partition I will post a screenshot in my question.

Comment: If it doesn't have a partition, then that is *unused space*. *Disks* are not mounted; it is the *partition on the disk* that is mounted. Look in *diskmgmt.msc*.

Comment: Yeah.. as DrMoishe said.. you really don't want to use A or B.. :)

Comment: So using A or B could be the reason this disk is causing trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely experiencing issues because drive letters A and B used to be reserved for old floppy drives. You should probably change the driver letter to something else not in use:

1. Open the start menu and type "Disk Management", it'll probably come up as "Create and format hard disk partitions"
2. Under volume find (A:), right click it and select "change drive letter and paths"

Keep in mind that any shortcuts that reference the old drive letter may stop working, as well as any programs that access files on that drive.